# "The method 'Cast' was called on null" is the problem i am currently having

Tags: json, flutter, dart, google-maps, dart-null-safety

i am trying to run a particular code to find quakes, when i run it however, i get "The method 'Cast' was called on null" and it doesnt seem to work, i dont know if that particular error is the reason because even when i found a way through this i still got a ' a resource failed to call release error'. This is the json model where the error is coming from

```
class EarthquakeModel {
  String? type;
  Metadata? metadata;
  List<Features>? features;
  List<double>? bbox;

  EarthquakeModel({this.type, this.metadata, this.features, this.bbox});

  EarthquakeModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    type = json['type'];
    metadata = json['metadata'] != null
        ? new Metadata.fromJson(json['metadata'])
        : null;
    if (json['features'] != null) {
      features = <Features>[];
      json['features'].forEach((v) {
        features!.add(new Features.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    bbox = json['bbox'].cast<double>();
  }
```

the bbox in particular.

And this is the code i am trying to run

```
class QuakeApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const QuakeApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<QuakeApp> createState() => _QuakeAppState();
}

class _QuakeAppState extends State<QuakeApp> {
  late Future<EarthquakeModel> quakeData;
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  List<Marker> _markerList = <Marker>[];
  

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    quakeData = Network().getEarthquake();

    //quakeData.then((value) => print('place: ${value.features?[0].properties?.place}'));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children:  [
            BuildGoogleMap(),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            _markerList.clear(); 
            setState(() {
              quakeData.then((quake) => {
                quake.features?.forEach((element) {
                  _markerList.add(Marker(markerId: MarkerId(element.id??''),    
                    infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                      title: element.properties?.mag?.toString(),
                    ),
                    icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueMagenta),
                    position: LatLng(element.geometry?.coordinates?[1]?? 0, element.geometry?.coordinates?[0]?? 0),
                    onTap: (){}
                  )
                  );
                })
              });
            });
          });
          },
          label: Text('Find Quakes')
      ),
    );
```

and this is the BuidGoogleMap method

```
class BuildGoogleMap extends StatefulWidget {
  const BuildGoogleMap({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BuildGoogleMap> createState() => _BuildGoogleMapState();
}

class _BuildGoogleMapState extends State<BuildGoogleMap> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  List<Marker> _markerList = <Marker>[];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(36.1083333, 117.8608333),
            zoom: 3
        ),
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller){
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
        markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markerList),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to check if the data is null or not.

try with

```dart
final data = json['bbox'] as List?;

if (data != null) {
  bbox = data.map((e) => double.tryParse(e) ?? 0.0).toList();
}
```